# After trying to run my code i get this in the console but not any other errors in my code: "Unexpected token ']'"

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
/**
* @title ContractName
* @dev ContractDescription
* @custom:dev-run-script election.sol
*/

contract Voting {
    struct Candidate {
        string name;
        uint CountVote;
    }

    struct Voter {
        bool authorized;
        bool voted;
        uint vote;
    }

    address payable public owner;
    string public electionName;

    mapping(address => Voter) voters;
    Candidate[] public Candidates;
    uint public VotesTotal;

    modifier ownerOnly(){
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor(string memory name) public {
        payable(msg.sender);

        electionName = name;
    }

    function addCandidate( string memory _name) ownerOnly public {
        Candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0));

    }

    function getNumCanditates() public view returns(uint) {
        return Candidates.length;
    }

    function authorize(address _person) ownerOnly public{
        voters[_person].authorized = true;
    }

    function vote(uint _VoteIndex) public {
        require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
        require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);

        voters[msg.sender].vote = _VoteIndex;
        voters[msg.sender].voted = true;

        Candidates[_VoteIndex].CountVote += 1;
        VotesTotal += 1;
    }

    function end() ownerOnly public {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: this error typically occurs when there is a syntax error in the code - in the code you posted seems like there is no `]` missing. maybe you can add more context and console output

Comment: ive tried that an i still get that